# Unable to build up Scala project using SBT plugin

Tags: java, scala, playframework, sbt

I think I'm going crazy building this thing. I have sources from an old project that I need to build, Scala + Play framework using SBT plugin. Firstly when I tried importing it to IntelliJ

```
SBT 0.12.4+ required. Please update project build.properties.
```

Then I went into **build.properties** and changed the `sbt.version` from `0.11.3` to `0.13.5`. Now it will show that

```
Unresolved dependencies:
play#sbt-plugin;2.0.4: not found
```

because in that repo there is not such plugin

```
==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.0.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.0.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/bdenis/.ivy2/local/play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.0.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   file:/home/bdenis/.sbt/preloaded/play/sbt-plugin/2.0.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:////home/bdenis/.sbt/preloaded/play/sbt-plugin_2.10_0.13/2.0.4/sbt-plugin-2.0.4.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/play/sbt-plugin_2.10_0.13/2.0.4/sbt-plugin-2.0.4.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/play/sbt-plugin_2.10_0.13/2.0.4/sbt-plugin-2.0.4.pom
```

Again, trying to dig into this problem, I have looked in the ivy-releases and maven-releases repos and haven't find a suitable version for my case to make it work, because in an end it will ask also for `sbt-link` plugin that is not in there as well. What choice do I have?

**plugins.sbt**

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.0.4")
```

**build.properties**

```
sbt.version=0.11.3
```

Comment: Well, looks like you have about two choices. a) Do without IntelliJ IDEA and work with an old school text editor. Or b) migrate the project to sbt 0.13. Which might mean that you have to compile all required and unavailable plugins for sbt 0.13 yourself.

Comment: You can also try [sbt-idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea/tree/sbt-0.11) (version `1.5.1` works for sbt 0.11) and use `gen-idea` to generate the IDEA project. Then, instead of importing the project, you just need to open it. Not sure it still works though.

Comment: @marcospereira, thanks for the tip, the one and only solution that worked was to remove old Build.scala config file and migrate it to build.sbt also to change versions of `sbt.version=0.13.15` and `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.6.6")`

@SaschaKolberg, thanks dude